# how to add an ImageButton inside a button in android

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

i want to make a button in another button , 
for example :
 we have 2 buttons : 1.imageButton (100 * 50)dp  , 2.button (100 * 100)dp 
so my question is how can i put my imageButton inside my button ?

Comment: Can you clarify? That doesn't make any sense, do you mean adding an image to a button?

Comment: no i can add image inside a button with android:drawableLeft or ...  .  my problem like this . i want to have button with image , when i clicking button do something and when i clicking image in button do other things

Comment: You add views inside layouts, not views inside views. You can simply add your image inside a layout and have different click events for layout and image button.

Comment: can you understand my problem ? for example in telegram android app , when you click on dialog you can see user or groups chat but when you click on dialog picture you can see chat or user information .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout` and just put second `ImageButton` over first `ImageButton`.

**Update**

Or You can use `magrin` in `LinearLayour`, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in linear layout it is impossible ?

Comment: Basically, if you want to make this type of functionality use relative layout and after adding relative layout then open your design view and drag and drop that image inside button

Comment: @b4hr4m yes, it possible in `LinearLayout`. You should use  `margins` to do that (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you..
You should use Frame Layout for this.
In XML file , do like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonsample"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And now in java file, declare the instance of Button and ImageButton

ImageButton imagebutton;

Button button;

In onCreate() function of java class, do....

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
imagebutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do your stuff
    }
});

imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Set z-elevation property if you want the buttons to overlap and both needs to be visibile. **android:elevation="2dp"**